# Is it possible to call Swift convenience initializer in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, swift

Say I have a convenience initializer in Swift:

```
extension UIImage {
    convenience init?(bundleNamed name: String) {
        let bundle = NSBundle(forClass: Foo.self)
        self.init(named: name, inBundle: bundle, compatibleWithTraitCollection: nil)
    }
}
```

How might I call this in Objective-C? The following doesn't work:

```
[UIImage bundleNamed:@"Bar"];
[[UIImage alloc] initWithBundleNamed:@"Bar"];
```

Do I need an additional class extension solely for Objective-C?

---

**Solution**: following Lasse's answer below, the steps I had to do were:

In the Objective-C classes implementation file, add

```
#import <ModuleName-Swift.h>
```

then I had to delete derived data and rebuild. Then I was able to use the convenience initializer as follows:

```
[[UIImage alloc] initWithBundleNamed: @"Bar"];
```

I didn't need to declare the initializer as `public` because the default level of `internal` was sufficient for my module.

Comment: What is the code for the method `initWithFoo:`? Just having `[Fooable foo:@"Bar"];` suggests that this is a class level method and not a instance level method

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Check out [Using Swift with Cocoa and Objective-C (Swift 2.2) - Mix and Match](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH10-ID122). What it seems to come down to is

1. Making your convenience initializer `public`, and
2. Importing an XCode-generated header file `[YourProductModuleName]-Swift.h` into your code

Comment: Of course! I didn't need to make the initializer `public` as the Obj-C code was in the same module. I've updated the question following your answer.

Answer (score 3):

> Yes we can use it **Note: @objc and public are important**

```
 @objc public init(url: URL) { 
   //your code 
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Please note! If you are using any of Swift features that are not available in Objective-C (like Optional values), it would not be accessible in Objective-C.
So fix them.

```
 public convenience init(title:String?, message:String?) {
    self.init()
    self.title = title
    self.message = message
}
```

Above code is not accessible, so removing optional will help in this case.