# How are Swift convenience constructors in extensions mapped to Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin-multiplatform, kotlin-multiplatform-mobile

How do I call this Swift extension convenience constructor from Kotlin?

```swift
public extension UIView {
  convenience init(svgData: Data, parser: SVGParser? = nil, completion: ((SVGLayer) -> ())? = nil) {
  ...
```

According to the [Interop documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/native-objc-interop.html#initializers), i was expecting that this should work:

```kotlin
create(svgData = data, parser = null, completion = null)
```

However, it doesn't compile (`Unresolved reference: create`) and it it seems like this approach would pollute the global namespace quite a bit. On the other hand, I can't really see a "canonical" mapping to some companinon object...

p.s. I have read that static extension functions are possible via the companion object in Kotlin, but `UIView.Companion.create(...)` doesn't seem to work either.

p.p.s.: As somebody had pointed out that the Kotlin mapping is based on ObjC (now deleted): perhaps this is relevant: [Is it possible to call Swift convenience initializer in Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36570564/is-it-possible-to-call-swift-convenience-initializer-in-objective-c/55515137) (didn't help me to figure out the mapping though)

Comment: Hi Stefan - Based on my experience with KMM, I understand that shared code can be written in Kotlin and called from Objective-C or Swift, but code written in Swift cannot be accessed from Kotlin (at least not with existing KMP tooling). KMP's interop with iOS enables Kotlin to access iOS Objective-C framework code, but Swift-only features (like Swift's Codable protocol) are unavailable. I include examples of how to map (existing iOS framework) Swift code to Kotlin in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73295668/1470581 Sorry I didn't see your question sooner! Best, Derek