# How to initialize NSOrderedSet in kotlin (Kotlin Multiplatform)

Tags: ios, swift, kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform, kotlin-multiplatform-mobile

I have a class with a contructor that with NSOrdered set as param, my secondary contructor will receive a collection and a comparator. I am not able to initiale NSOrdered as no contructors exists that converts array to NSOrderedSet

```
class IOSSortedSet<T>(private val list: NSOrderedSet) : SortedSet<T> {

    constructor(
        comparator: Comparator<in T>,
        collection: Iterable<T>
    ) : this(NSOrderedSet(collection.sortedWith(comparator).toList())). //Incorrect
```

Basically the line `NSOrderedSet(collection.sortedWith(comparator).toList())` is incorrect. Please help me with the correct syntax.

This is the only constructors available on Kotlin:
[image]

Comment: Have you had a chance to review my answer? Did this provide the information you were looking for? If not, please let me know what additional information would be helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This question, [as is the case with several others relating to how to write Kotlin/Native code for iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73295668/1470581), is best solved by referencing Apple's [Objective-C documentation for NSOrderedSet](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsorderedset?language=objc) (instead of the Swift documentation).

This shows various options for creating NSOrderedSet, and note that these are all class methods (annotated with a `+`) [as opposed to instance methods](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1053592/1470581) (annotated with a `-`). (*Having a basic understanding of Objective-C and how to read the language can be quite helpful in this case.*)

[image: Apple NSOrderedSet Objective-C Documentation showing how to create NSOrderedSet objects]

Since these are class methods, in Kotlin, these can be found on the `.Companion` object of `NSOrderedSet`:

[image: Android Studio code completion for Kotlin/Native NSOrderedSet.Companion]

Since you mentioned creating an NSOrderedSet from an array, I would guess that the `orderedSetWithArray` method might be what you're looking for.

There are two variations of this method: [one that takes just an array](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsorderedset/1543310-orderedsetwitharray?language=objc) (or a List in Kotlin), and [another that takes an array along with a range and boolean indicator for copying items or not](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsorderedset/1543321-orderedsetwitharray?language=objc).

[image: Sample Kotlin code with IDE pop-over illustrating possible arguments for the orderedSetWithArray method]

While sometimes it can be possible to dig through the Kotlin/Native header files (at least, I haven't found an effective way to search through these yet...), in this case, the Foundation class definitions appear to be quite spread out, so I'd recommend using the Objective-C documentation as a starting point instead.

[image: Kotlin/Native Foundation APIs for NSOrderedSet]

Comment: If you want to dig deeper, I also published a blog post on writing iOS-platform-dependent code using Kotlin with KMM's expect/actual: https://artandscienceofcoding.com/science/avoid-this-kmm-technique/